# how to set the "delete project contents on disk" option by default in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

When I delete a project from Eclipse, I want it to always get deleted from workspace as well, but I always forget to check the option to do so.
Is it possible to keep this option enabled by default?

This is the option I am talking about:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This page of the delete resources wizard is:

```
org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.resource.DeleteResourcesWizard.DeleteResourcesRefactoringConfigurationPage
```

Unfortunately there is nothing in the code to set a default value for this option so it can't be changed.

Comment: Could you please tell what does it mean by `This page of the delete resources wizard` ? Where can I find out more about this?

Comment: The image you posted is shown by the delete resources wizard `org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardDialog2` which displays two dialog pages - the first is the page I quoted, the second is the delete preview page shown if you click `Preview>`.